# Are there any reasons for using Huber over the Pseudo Huber Loss?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-function

> The Huber Loss is:  $$ huber = 
>      \begin{cases}
>        \frac{1}{2}  t^2 & \quad\text{if}\quad |t|\le \beta \\
>        \beta |t| -\frac{\beta^2}{2} &\quad\text{else} 
>      \end{cases} $$
> The pseudo huber is:
> $$ pseudo = \delta^2\left(\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{t}{\delta}\right)^2}-1\right)$$

What are the pros and cons of using pseudo huber over huber? I don't really see much research using pseudo huber, so I wonder why?

For me, pseudo huber loss allows you to control the smoothness and therefore you can specifically decide how much you penalise outliers by, whereas huber loss is either MSE or MAE. Also, the huber loss does not have a continuous second derivative.

So, what exactly are the cons of pseudo, if any?

Comment: Same question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/509447/whats-the-pros-and-cons-between-huber-and-pseudo-huber-loss-functions